# Angular 10/11: The pipe 'ngrxPush' could not be found

Tags: angular, ngrxpush

When trying to use ngrxPush-pipe, I'm getting following error:
"The pipe 'ngrxPush' could not be found"

I have installed the ngrx component:

```
npm install @ngrx/component --save

package.json: "@ngrx/component": "^10.0.1"
```

I'm importing the pipe in AppModule:

```
import { ReactiveComponentModule } from '@ngrx/component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
     ReactiveComponentModule
  ],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

And calling the pipe from AppComponent's template:

```html
<vk-navigation *ngIf="!!(loaded$ | async)" [navigation]="navigation$ | ngrxPush"
  (toggleMenu)="setMenu($event)" (navigate)="navigatePath($event)">
</vk-navigation>
```

Any ideas what could go wrong?
Error occurs in Angular 10 & 11, with NgRx component/10.

Tried also to disable Ivy with no luck for solving the error.

Navigation.component.ts:

```
export class NavigationComponent {

  @Input() navigation: any;

  @Output() navigate = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() toggleMenu = new EventEmitter();

  get showMenu() {
    return this.navigation.showMenu;
  }

  get showPrevNav() {
    return this.navigation.prev != null;
  }

  get showNextNav() {
    return !!this.navigation.next;
  }

  @HostBinding('class.navigationIsActive') get c1 () { return this.showMenu; }

  constructor() { }

}
```

App.component.ts:

```
export class AppComponent{

  loaded$: Observable<boolean>;
  showMenu$: Observable<boolean>; 
  navTree$: Observable<any>;
  currentPathId$: Observable<number>;
  currentDataId$: Observable<number>;
  navigation$: Observable<any>;
  
  constructor(private store: Store<fromRoot.State>, private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) {

    this.loaded$ = store.pipe(select(fromRoot.selectLoaded));
    this.showMenu$ = store.pipe(select(fromRoot.selectShowMenu));
    this.navTree$ = store.pipe(select(fromRoot.selectNavTree)); 
    this.currentPathId$ = store.pipe(select(fromRoot.selectSelectedPathId));
    this.currentDataId$ = store.pipe(select(fromContact.selectSelectedQuestionId));
    this.navigation$ = store.pipe(select(fromRoot.selectNavigation)); 
    
    const wheel$ = fromEvent(document, 'wheel').pipe(
      throttleTime(300),
      tap((event) => event['deltaY'] > 0 ? this.navigatePath('next') : this.navigatePath('prev')) 
      ).subscribe();
  }

  @HostListener('swipedown', ['$event.target'])
    onSwipeDown(){this.navigatePath('prev')}

  @HostListener('swipeup', ['$event.target'])
    onSwipeUp(){this.navigatePath('next')}

  navigatePath(i: string){
    this.navigation$.pipe(
      map(nav => nav[i]),
      take(1),
      filter(nav => nav != null && nav != undefined)
    ).subscribe(nav => (typeof nav === 'number') ? 
    this.store.dispatch(LayoutActions.navigateDataObject({objectID:nav })) : 
    this.router.navigate([nav]) );
  }

  setMenu(showMenu:boolean){
    if(showMenu === true)
      this.store.dispatch(LayoutActions.closeMenu());
    else
      this.store.dispatch(LayoutActions.openMenu());
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.store.dispatch(LayoutActions.getPaths());
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you provide more content about your template, where you put your `[navigation]="navigation$ | ngrxPush"` content,  on which element you put the navigation property ?

Comment: Here is the whole part of template where it is used:
<vk-navigation *ngIf="!!(loaded$ | async)" [navigation]="navigation$ | ngrxPush" (toggleMenu)="setMenu($event)" (navigate)="navigatePath($event)"></vk-navigation>

Comment: Can you add the typescript class file as well to the question ? (for the component vk-navigation)

Comment: Updated both to the question

Comment: It seems to be a bug in NgRx/component 10.0.1.
I downgraded to 10.0.0 and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should first install the relevant package:

```
npm install @ngrx/component --save
```

or

```
yarn add @ngrx/component
```

probably you missed this step,

And then you can add it to your `app.module.ts` file:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ReactiveComponentModule } from '@ngrx/component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    // other imports
    ReactiveComponentModule
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Tested working well under:

```
"@angular/core": "~10.2.1"
```

installed package under package.json:

```
"@ngrx/component": "^10.0.1"
```

Comment: This is not the case as I have installed the ngrx component:
from package.json: "@ngrx/component": "^10.0.1"

Answer (score 0):

There are several reason why this may occur

### You may not have installed the package.

This has been covered by @HDJEMAI in his solution

### You may not have imported the `ReactiveComponentModule` in the module.

This is especially more often in lazy loaded modules and shared modules where you import the module in the `AppModule` but you forget to import it in `SomeLazyLoadedModule`. You will experience the same error

### Cache problems

This is the most frustrating of the errors. You have implemented everything correctly but for some reason it doesn't work! The solution is usually to restart the server, restart the IDE or restart both and everything works